# Removing an item from a Dynamic Array List in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to get used to writing C by writing some simple programs, I wanted to try my hand at writing a dynamic Array List in C. So far it works, but I'm not exactly sure how the remove item would be implemented, for example:

There's a list which contains some values, e.g:

```
index   value
0       "a"
1       "b"
2       "c"
3       "d"
```

Say I were to remove the value at the index 2 `remove_item(list, 2)`, the values would be as follows:

```
index   value
0       "a"
1       "b"
2       NULL
3       "d"
```

But this would probably give me some undefined behaviour, which isn't ideal. So my question is, how can I shift the data over to fill in the gaps, e.g removing the index at 2 shifts it:

```
index   value
0       "a"
1       "b"
2       "d"
```

**edit**:
I've implemented the second example, but I'm not sure how I would go around making it behave as shown in example 3. The programs structure is pretty simple:

```
typedef struct ArrayList {
    int array_size;
    void **items;
} ArrayList;
```

Any help would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
index   value
0       "a"
1       "b"
2       "c"
3       "d"
```

Call `remove_item(list, 2);`

Now your list should appear like this:

```
index   value
0       "a"
1       "b"
2       "d"
```

In other words, every index actually represents a node. You wish to delete the node with index (you could say id too) 2. You delete the node with index two. Now you actually connect the node 1 with node 3. However, since indexing is incremental, you decrease the index of the next node by one, thus 3 becomes 2.

When I was in my first semester, out professor taught us the simple linked list, via [this](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/list-c/) code. It was really helpful for me. Make sure you read the comments. By posting this link, it means I trust you don't want just to make some hw, but to learn. :) It's not exactly what you are implementing, but it can get use to the idea.

Comment: What library is that?

Comment: There is no library @Igor. I am just saying how the list would be after a deletion happens, assuming we have some code with the relevant functionality.

Comment: Thanks! Having a read now, and homework? I wish I could do C at school :)

Comment: No I mean that I hope you are not just another user that wants its hw done by others. :) You are welcome.